# Python Classes in Classes

Tags: python, class

I have a simulation python code, which I would like to convert into a class structure for ease of use.

[image]

Now, my question is: I know how to setup a normal class, ie:

```
class simulation:
     def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name

     def geometry(self):

     def calculation(self):

etc.
```

...but how do I incorporate the subinstances i.e. circle, rectangles ?

Basically, in the end, I want to be able to write something like: `simulation.geometry.circle(...)`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class Simulation:
    """Outer Class"""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        ## instantiating the 'Inner' class
        #self.geometry = self.Geometry()

    def print_name(self):
        print("name: ", self.name)

    class Geometry(Simulation):
        """Inner Class"""

        def circle(self, radius,center):
            print("name of simulation: ", self.name)
            print("radius: ", center)
            print("position: ", center)

        def rectangle(self, center):
            print("position: ", center)
```

Now, if I try:

```
## instantiating the outer class
sim = Simulation("version_1")
## instantiating the inner class
geo = sim.Geometry()      

geo.circle(radius=10,center=[0,0])
```

I get the error:

> ```
> line 34, in <module>
>     geo = sim.Geometry()
>
> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
> ```

How can I fix this ? Basically, I want to inert the self. parameters from the superclass also to the subclasses.

**EDIT:**

I tried to have Geometry inert from Simulation...

```
class Simulation:
    # parent class 

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        ## instantiating the 'Inner' class
        #self.geometry = self.Geometry()

    def print_name(self):
        print("name: ", self.name)

class Geometry(Simulation):
    # child class 


    def circle(self, radius,center):
        print("name of simulation: ", self.name)
        print("radius: ", center)
        print("position: ", center)

    def rectangle(self, center):
        print("position: ", center)
```

...but I get the error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Comment: Classes almost never need to be defined in a nested way like you are doing here. Keeping your class definitions separate makes it much easier to reason about their relationships.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh How do you inherit then the self. from one class to the next ? Would you mind to rewrite my small example as you would structure it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would either pass the `Simulation` to `Geometry.__init__` or pass it to the individual methods of `Geometry`.  Without knowing more about what you're actually trying to do I can't really recommend a design. Try to think if it's really necessary that  the objects "under" `Simulation` need to know about their `Simulation`s, or if it's sufficient for them to accept arguments to methods.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I would like to initialize a simulation class with all the general parameters (i.e. paths, simulation size, simulation time etc.) those parameters should then be handed to all the specific classes like the geometry classes, where you can set the geometry, i.e. radius etc. Those specifc classes need to access the general parameters from time to time, to know for instance where to save data to. 

I hope that this makes it a bit clearer what I am looking for ?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh see the update

Comment: @henry Inheritance is not what you want to do here. Inheritance is for when you have one class that is going to behave similarly to another class. For instance you may have a general `geometry` object, and a `square` object. Because a `square` is `geometry`, you would have `square` inherit from `geometry`. That way it behaves like `geometry`, but the only difference is that `square` is a very specific `geometry` with 4 vertices and 4 edges of equal length. In your case `Simulation` and `Geometry` are two different classes that do two different things so inheritance is not what you want.

Comment: @Jmonsky Okay, so ...uhm... what do I want ? haha :)  Sorry to ask so boldly, it is just a bit confusing to me. How can I achieve what I have described in the comment ?

Comment: @henry I believe what you want is to create a module. You can find a good resource on how to do this here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-modules-in-python-3

Comment: @Jmonsky thanks a lot for your comment, i will check it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from `Simulation` without overriding the `__init__` constructor function. Since you do not override it uses the `__init__` from `Simulation` which takes 1 argument.

To note, `Geometry` cannot inherit from `Simulation` since it is a component of it. If you would like it to, you should move the class `Geometry` out of `Simulation`. But you likely do not want that if you want to be able to call `Simulation.Geometry...`, which you cant do through inheritance.

If you want to be able to call attributes of `Simulation` of `Geometry` you can reference it by saying `Simulation.attribute`, but you cannot access instance variables like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't understand how to change the code to make it work, though. How would I need to alter the code ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mention you want to be able to call `Simulation.Geometry.circle()` like you would a module. But you also instantiate the classes by saying `sim = Simulation('name')`. Do you want to instantiate these objects and use them as objects, or do you want classes to act as a structure for a set of methods?

Comment: I am not to familiar with the terminology, hence I will describe you want I would like to be able to: I would like to initialize a simulation class with all the general parameters, those parameters should then be handed to all the spcific classes, like the geometry classes, where you can set the geometry, i.e. radius etc.